# Графики в iOS

Tags: график, objective-c, ios, гистограммы

Задача, построить гистограмму, а поверх нее нарисовать график.

Подскажите, что можно посмотреть в данном направлении?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использовал [CorePlot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot). Довольно хороший и мощный, правда малость запутанный фреймворк.

Comment: Безпощадная Жесть! +1

Comment: Его мне и советовали, будем разбираться
Может тут еще что-то посоветуют

Answer (score 1):

Вообще тема интересная. Но ни как до нее руки не доходили, поэтому погуглите:

1. [Гугл](https://www.google.ru/search?q=grafics+ios+library&oq=grafics+ios+library&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.10421j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=Histogram+ios)
2. [Вот это](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dsbarchart)
3. [Это](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/vImage_histogram/Reference/reference.html)
4. [Ну и это](https://github.com/HarshitDaftary/Generate-Histogram-Graph-For-an-Image-in-iPhone)

P.S. Очень инетересно что вы найдете, отпишите пожалуйста о результатах.

Comment: Несколько человек, включая @szarajewski посоветовали core-plot.
Мельком глянул ваши ссылки, все только про гистограммы, но мне надо нарисовать 2 графика и наложить их друг на друга, и желательно, чтобы это можно было сделать 1 библиотекой, core-plot это может, как я понял. Буду с ней разбираться